# Convert IPTC keywords to blog post tags

Tags: posts, taxonomy, tags

I'm a total newbie regarding to wp or coding or anything like that but I manage to get things done with a bit of reading. 
I need a way to convert IPTC extracted keywords that are attached to it's media file to a blog post tags.

This is my workflow - I upload an image, image get's attached to a post as featured image, it get's watermarked, it has a link to original size. The image itself has keywords, name, description etc...

Everything is almost automated. Upload with media uploader, everything above happens on autopilot, except I need to copy the media file keywords from the media page to that blog post tags.

Is there a way I can assign keywords from an image attached to a post to automatically add themselves to that blog post tags?

Answer (score 3):

WordPres has a function that extract IPTC info from images, that function is `wp_read_image_metadata`. That function is only available on admin side and, [according with the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_read_image_metadata), it doesn't extract IPTC keywords. But you can use [`iptcparse` from PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.iptcparse.php) at your own to extract IPTC keywords and set them as post tags.

In your question, you said that you have already automated the proccess to attach the image as featured image of the post, so you can easily grab the image ID and the post ID during that proccess. Once you have attached the image to the post, store the post ID in `$post_ID` and the image ID in `$image_ID` and then you could do something like this:

```
$image = getimagesize( get_attached_file( $image_ID ), $info );

if( isset( $info['APP13'] ) ) {

   $iptc = iptcparse( $info['APP13'] );

   // 2#025 is the key in the iptc array for keywords
   if( isset( $iptc['2#025'] ) && is_array( $iptc['2#025'] ) ) {

        // Last param is true to append these tags to existing tags,
        // set it to false to replace existing tags
        // See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_tags
        wp_set_post_tags( $post_ID, $iptc['2#025'], true );

   }

}
```

If you set the featured image using `set_post_thumbnail` function (using the edit post screen to set the featured image use that function as well), you could hook the above code to `updated_post_meta` action (`set_post_thumbnail` use metadata to set the featured image):

```
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', function( $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value ) {

    // Check that meta 
    if( $meta_key == '_thumbnail_id' ) {

        $image = getimagesize( get_attached_file( $_meta_value ), $info );

        if( isset( $info['APP13'] ) ) {

            $iptc = iptcparse( $info['APP13'] );

            if( isset( $iptc['2#025'] ) && is_array( $iptc['2#025'] ) ) {

                wp_set_post_tags( $object_id, $iptc['2#025'], true );

            }

        }


    }

}, 10, 4 );
```

**Note**: code not tested. Just written here. You may need to handle also when the featured image is removed or changed.

**Note2**: I've re-read your question and notice that you are (quoting you) "newbie regarding to wp or coding or anything like that". Not sure if you will understand the code above and I think the second block of code can be more helpful to you than the first.

Comment: how would be the best way to check if there's XMP data, then if yes, use XMP, and if not, check and use IPTC instead?

Answer (score -1):

It depends. To extract the IPTC keywords you will have to find a library or a code sample that you can use as I don't remember anything in wordpress doing that.

As for using the keywords as tags for posts, in theory it is possible. The main issue with it is that images are not attached to posts in a "hard" way. A post just includes a url of an image so while an image might be display in the admin as being associated with the post in which it was uploaded, it is not restricted to appear only there. So the tricky part is to decide which images should be used as the source of the tags.